# xxd how to output just hex bytes, no whitespace

Tags: xxd

Using the xxd command, is it possible to read one byte at a time from the input and to output one byte at a time. No spaces, no newlines, no ending newline?

I tried the columns setting and did not get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Try `xxd -p`

It should do what you have asked for.

```
~ $ printf abc | xxd -p
616263
```